# Authentication is Disabled

Tags: authentication

On my Mac Mini, I am trying to update Alfred. So, I hit the update button and get prompted for an Admin username and password, which I provide correctly. However, I get an Authentication is Disabled message.

Another answer stated to log in on the Admin account and run some commands. However, when I try to log in on the Admin Account, I get the "Authentication is Disabled" message and cannot log in.

So, how can this issue be fixed? I am currently unable to update my MacOS nor many of my apps to later versions due to this bug.

Comment: 1) "Another answer" - what other answer? 2) Does your Mac link to an Active Directory? 3) Is your Mac "managed" by a work IT group?

Comment: 1) the answer from the question that is referenced in the Duplicated box. 2) No 3) No

Comment: So it seems not to be duplicate as the other question if very much Active Directory. Nevertheless have you tried the `pwpolicy` commands at the end of the answer?

Comment: Do I run it on another account? I only have the main account and the admin account, and the admin account is locked.

Comment: I think you need another admin account.  Add a comment to the other answer asking about that.

Comment: I'm new so I don't have the reputation to comment, but I cannot add a new account as the admin account is locked and I can't add a new account without it.